# Avoid Next.js runtime error with axios exception in API route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, axios

I'm trying to make an API route in Next that send a request to my backend and saves the token in the cookies, but `4xx` responses throw an Unhandled runtime error. Everything works fine, but I got this runtime error; I want to handle the error by myself instead of getting this:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

```
import { signIn } from '@/services/auth'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function signInHandler (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { userName, password } = req.body
  const response = await signIn({ userName, password }).catch(e => e.response)
  if (response.status === 200) {
    // save token in cookies
  }
  return res.status(response.status).json(response.data)
}
```

```
// signIn
export const signIn = ({ userName, password }: {userName: string, password: string}) =>
  api.post(`${baseEndpoint}/sign-in`, { userName, password })

// api
export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseApiUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

[image: Next runtime error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply wrap your request with `axios` inside a [`try-catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). As an example like below:

```
import { signIn } from "@/services/auth";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function signInHandler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { userName, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const response = await signIn({ userName, password }).catch((e) => e.response);
    // save token in cookies
    return res.status(response.status).json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    // add the logic for when a sign-in fails here
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem was that I made the API call in the log in form component, and I forgot to write the catch there... thank you!